# Change "Error" label in stop function on R

Tags: r

Is it possible to change the **Error** label inside the `stop()` function?

For example:

```
stop("This is a error!")
```

> Error: This is a error!

change to:

> Incorrect: This is a error!

I need to use `stop` function, not `warning` or `message` functions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a risk that this could be confusing for users seeing something that's an stopping the code without explicitly announcing that it's an error.

If you can guarantee that the user is using English, you can hack it a bit using the backspace character (`\b`) with:

```
stop("\b\b\b\b\b\b\bIncorrect: This is a error!")
```

but this relies on knowing how long the word "Error" is in English, a version that also works in other languages would be trickier.

Edited to add that even in English this doesn't work from inside a function:

```
throw_an_error <- function()stop("\b\b\b\b\b\b\bIncorrect: This is a error!")
throw_an_error()
# Error in throw_an_errIncorrect: This is a error!
```